# Does Discriminator in GAN Train only on Real Data or it also Trains on Fake Generated Data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning, gan

I have been studying GANs and I got confused in the training phase from the discriminator. Which I think only trains on Real data, not on the generated data which then helps in distinguishing or classifying whether the input is real or fake. I need to confirm that is true what I am thinking or if it does train on fake data generated by the generator as well.

Answer (score 1):

The input to the complete GAN is only the real data, so the complete GAN only trains on the real data.

But the discriminator part of the GAN learns to distinguish between the generated and real data, so it also trains on the generated data.

Imagine the generator does a really bad job in learning to fool the discriminator, e.g. it is only creating complete random data or constant data. Then clearly the discriminator would not become good at detecting the real data and the whole GAN would not work. So the quality of the generator influences the evolution of the discriminator, which shows that the discriminator learns from the generated data, too.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I have a doubt. The generator will output a single image every time. Whereas real data can be of thousands. So, what I was thinking is if rather it trains on generated data it trains on some other fake data (not the generated ones).

Comment: I am not sure I understand your last sentence. But note that with GANs we want to create a generator and we get a good one by fitting the discriminator "against" the generator, so both make each other better. You could also throw in some fake data that is not from the generator, but in the end, it is the generator that should be trained.

Comment: From what I have researched though I am a beginner you can correct me if I am wrong. What I get about how the gan works is that. First, we feed real data to GAN on which discriminator trains on. After training on it. discriminator stops and generator training starts, the generator gets the noisy data (Which can be either different orientations, textures, etc.) then it generates the data which then goes into discriminator which then predicts whether it's real or fake. (Initially, it can easily predict it fake as initially the generator won't be efficient or mature enough to fool discriminator)

Comment: After that when it runs for more iterations it may get capable to fool the discriminator. So what you have written when the data gets generated also gets to the discriminator on which discriminator trains again? that's what I got from the message Right?

Comment: The discriminator and generator take turns in training. First, the discriminator is trained, then the generator, then the discriminator, ... and so on, for quite some time.

Comment: So, What I have written is correct. Right?

Comment: If you meant this, then yes.